# How do I find words that only consist of the given set of characters within the word

Tags: java, regex

I wish to loop through a dictionary file and find words that contain only the given characters

Example *dgo* which contains the letters "d", "o" and "g"

*go*,*dog*, and *god* would set **ans = true** as they use letters from the original word with as many characters as the original word has.

*doog*, *good*, *dogo* would keep **ans = false** as they all contain a letter from the original word that has been used more than once.

"Doog" uses "o" twice.
"Good" uses "o" twice.
"Goddd" uses "d" thrice.

What would I change with the if loop to account for if a character is used more than how many times it appears in the original string

```
public boolean goodWord(String test){

        //Test to see if characters are in the original word

        boolean ans =false;

        String checker = "[" + test+ "]*"); //Problem with this line

        if (test.matches(checker)) {
            ans = true;
        }

}
```

Comment: Your question is missing a clear problem description. Thus read [mcve] and maybe https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question ... you are not saying for example what **type** your *dict* variable has!

Comment: The question is perfectly clear. This is how to do it with a single regex [^(?=(?:(.)(?!.*?\1))+$)(?=.*d)(?=.*o)(?=.*g)\[dog\]{3}$](https://regex101.com/r/gC3hd7/1) It would be nice to reopen this up to properly explain the technique. To all those who voted to close - _It shows ignorance to close something just because you don't know how to solve it._ Give someone a chance to show you how to do it, you might learn something.

Comment: How would I do that given a changing String  variable test instead of "dog"

Answer (score 3):

```
String checker = "[" + test+ "]{" + test.length() + "}";
```

According to the comment, here is the new version

```
String checker = "";
for (int i = 1; i < test.length(); i++)
   checker += "([" + test + "])(?!\" + i + ")";
```

So for example for string "dog" it should look like `"([dog])(?!\1)([dog])?(?!\1|\2)[dog]?"`

Comment: What I'm looking for is to only use the letter the amount of times that it is in the original word. "D", "o" and "g" are only present 1 time and if a word uses one of those letters more than once, it shouldn't count

Comment: Look at my last edits

Comment: How does it set ans to true or false ?